# Can I uninitialize earthengine?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm benchmarking different implementation of a workflow based on the GEE Python API. The code does something as the following:

```py
%%timeit

ee.Initialize()

# do ee related stuff
```

I would assume that between 2 tests `ee` does not need to initialize again. Can I manually reverse any action done by ee.Initialize() to make sure that every run is made on the same basis?

Comment: It's unlikely that this is possible. The comparison would be more valid if you ran each test multiple times, plus a set of runs with just initialization, then removed the mean initialization cost from both.

Comment: what I want to benchmark is the diff between using [highvolume ](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/cloud/highvolume) and regular init on a specific task, so the init time is part of what I want to test. Currently I'm running a .py script N time from the console, but who knows maybe I could do it in a cell

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you can reset the API (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-reset)

> Reset the library to its base state. Useful for re-initializing to a different server.

```py
ee.reset()
```